# mongoose: shorten attribute names of node.js models for storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bson

In C# it is possible to use the MongoDB driver to define a custom BSONElement Name to each attribute in your data model, in order to shorten its stored name, such as

```
[BsonElement("n")]
public String Name { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with **mongoose** for node.js in a model defined like

```
var Project = new Schema({
    id  : ObjectId,
    name: String,
});
mongoose.model("Project", Project);
```

so that the attribute "name" will be stored as "n" and be referenced in code as "name"?

Researching the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) did not work very well on this one. Thanks!

Comment: There is actually a plan to significantly reduce the storage of key names by hashing however there is no server-side implementation of any storage saving stuff yet and I do not believe node.js provides this out of the box as such it most likely is down to you do create a mapping layer, however the storage difference of `name` to `n` is not a good example. A better example is the storage size of `Some_total_awesome_field_i_want_now` to `s`.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data stored a few attributes reduced by a few bytes could become mildly interesting. I thought maybe mongoose would offer something like name: {type: String, alias: "n"}. That's what my question aims at.

Comment: You could likely use Mongoose's support for [virtual attributes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) to achieve this.

Comment: Additionally to show that there is a reasonable need to shorten your fieldnames, see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/44144228891/mongodb-tip-create-short-field-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin where you can specify alias names, so that you can store single letter fields in the DB, but have really_long_names in your code:

https://github.com/ramiel/Alias-Field-Mongoose-plugin